# Recovering 3D from inverse disparity and instinct matrix

Tags: geometry, computer-vision

I am facing the challenge to recover the Z coordinate from an inverse disparity map and the instinct matrix K. The Z coordinate does not have to be metric but it has to be scale aware.

$$
  K_{3\times 3} =
  \left[ 
   {\begin{array}{cccc}
    721 & 0 & 596 \\
    0 & 721 & 149 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

I know that $z=f\frac{T}{d}$ where T is the distance between two coplanar cameras, f is the focal length, and d is the disparity. However, I am not told any extrinsic other than the camera is 1.5m up from the floor. The disparity is already an inverse disparity so I guess $z=f \times d$? Also, what do I do with the other parameters in my K matrix (596, 149)? Any help is welcome.